# ionic 5 and cordova - build error: xcworkspace is not a workspace file when building for iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 5 - Cordova  project (Cordova CLI 10, Ionic Framework 5.3.2). When I try to build for iOS I get the error:

**xcodebuild: error: '._[PROJECT NAME].xcworkspace' is not a workspace file.
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 66**

If I remove the iOS platform and I add it back again I can build but as soon as I do it a second time the problem reappear.